# How do I edit KO template in magento 2

Tags: payment-methods, knockoutjs, magento2.2.2, checkout-page, ui

I wish to edit `/var/www/html/xxx/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html`

Exactly in below line, Because which is the responsible file to render the template for each payment method. I wish to change the look of the payment method in Magento 2

> each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'"
>   render=""

Comment: What are the changes would you like to make in payment method?

Comment: I wish to display payment methods(1. netbanking , 2. credit card 3. COD) as a list. And  Wish to add common input field which is hidden for all the methods.While placing a order the value which is present in input field should be submitted

Comment: What about the billing address under each payment method?

Comment: I have disabled the billing address js component

Comment: I dont want need billing address section to display

Comment: can you tell me what the above code doing

Answer (score 0):

#### Using theme:

You can copy corresponding template in your theme (saving original path) and change data in template according your needs.

copy original template

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html

in your theme

> app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{themeName}/{packageName}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/payment-methods/list.html

and edit it per your needs.

#### In third-party module:

add dependency in the `module.xml`

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="{Vendor_Module}" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create own template file with appropriate content:

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/web/template/payment-method/list.html

Default content example (the `h3` tag is added for test purposes):

```
<h3>Payment Methods List</h3>
<div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="items payment-methods">
    <div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
         class="payment-group">
        <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

Update layout:

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">{Vendor_Module}/payment-method/list</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Clean cache; Deploy static content; Check result:**

[image: result on checkout payment step]